# variable для перевода px в vh

Tags: css, scss

Нашел в инете данную формулу расчета , но не знаю , как по мне оно делает чуток текст и все остальное чуток меньше, чем на макете , может кто-то знает подобные функции и подскажет свою ?

```css
@function get-vh($object) {
  $vh: (1080 * 0.01) * 1px;
  @return ($object / $vh) * 1vh;
}
```

Comment: Если у вас высота страницы в браузере чуток меньше чем 1080 пикселей, то с таким расчётом вполне логично, что всё на этой странице тоже будет чуток меньше чем 1080 пикселей

Comment: Я не указывал у себя ни где высоту браузера , по дефолту 100% стоит , как лучше тогда посоветуете это исправить ? @andreymal

Comment: Сверху над браузером есть заголовок окна, под заголовком есть панель браузерных вкладок и адресная строка, снизу под браузером есть панель задач — это уже по умолчанию отъедает чуток пикселей у страницы, даже если вы нигде ничего нигде не меняли

Comment: «как лучше тогда посоветуете это исправить» — а какого результата вы хотите добиться? Если вы хотите полное соответствие макету — просто используйте пиксели и не надо изобретать никаких vh

Comment: Ну как я понимаю , vh нужно для адаптива, думал , что-то с этим сделать

Comment: Тогда надо сперва предварительно продумать, какой конкретно адаптив на всех ожидаемых размерах экрана должен быть и верстать с оглядкой на желаемое поведение, а не лепить везде vh и надеяться что прокатит)